# writing data to CSV file very slow android studio(kotlin) with apache library

Tags: android, kotlin, csv

I am writing a android app in kotlin.
im creating couple of CSV files for it from within app(one time creation) one csv file has around 43200 lines.12 csv files separately.

but app spend 60 seconds to write 1600 lines.. is there any way to make this code faster?

```
fun startcreatingcsv() {
  
val File_Path = this.getExternalFilesDir(null).toString() + "/1993.csv"
    val writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(File_Path))
    val csvPrinter = CSVPrinter(
        writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader(
            "Name",
            "sex",
            "Birthyear",
            "Birthmonth",
            "Birthday"
        )
    )
     var tempcount=0

    for(tempcount in 1..43200) {
      tempcount++

        csvPrinter.printRecord(
            "Mark",
            "Male",
            "1993",
            "12",
            "25"
        )

    }

    csvPrinter.flush()
    csvPrinter.close()

}
```

I know its writing same line over and over for 42000 times.I simplified the code to understand better. Thanks. Any help appreciated

below method also spends the same time to write..

```
    val File_Path = this.getExternalFilesDir(null).toString() + "/1993.csv"
    val writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(File_Path))
    val writer = bufferedWriter()
    writer.write("Name,sex,Birthyear,Birthmonth,Birthday")
    writer.newLine()
   var tempcount=0
   for(tempcount in 1..43200) {
      tempcount++
    writer.write("Mark,Male,1993,12,25")
        writer.newLine()
    }
    writer.flush()
```